# Align text in treeview node

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a treeview and i bind text to the nodes . Now if the text increases in its length it moves on to the next line . This next line start one place before the upper text resulting in in proper alignment . Is there any css or any way where in i can call some javascript method and align it properly.

[image: Align]

Regards,
Francis P.

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/navigate1.htm

Comment: Its a normal TreeView where in i do a Datasource and then a databind
So code will be 
_trreview.DataSource="Some collection"
_treeview.DataBind()

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the child node of the tree in a span. Then add margin-left:5px or what ever to make sure you align it with respect to the tree node.